# Solving Distorted Image Captcha With PHP

Tags: php, image, captcha, solver

I was wondering if theres a way for solving a distorted image captcha with PHP?
The captcha has a list of 6 images which are always distorted in different ways and asks to drag n drop the correct one. The captchas are usually in different colours, they are of regular items (for example, a man, an eye, a house, a clock etc).

The following are examples of what pants would look like

[image: Pants]
[image: Pants]
[image: Pants]

An example of a truck from the captcha would be:
[image: Truck]
[image: Truck]
[image: Truck]

The main problem is actually getting the PHP script to work out what image corresponds to what item, the "dragndrop" is done by simply editing a hidden input element to a data attribute thats on the image element

Anyone have any idea how i would go about doing this?
Thanks all help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*I wanted to comment on this question but since I don't have the reputation points I give an answer*

Are you sure that you want to implement the captcha yourself? There are several libraries which you can use to implement a captcha in PHP:

- https://www.phpcaptcha.org
- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html --> I think this can be used in combination with Javascript

Besides that, I think it is important to you first try to write the script yourself and ask questions about that script if you're stuck.

**Edit**
If you send the identifiers (e.g. a name) of the images with the form (assuming you use a form) to the server. The respective image is then available through the POST super global. Example:

```
<form action="your_script.php">
  <select name="image">
      <option value="image-1">image-1</option>
      <option value="image-2">image-2</option>
      <option value="image-3">image-3</option>
      <option value="image-4">image-4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Furthermore, use some Javascript (or jQuery) to assign the right option based on which image the user clicked. On the server side (when the form is submitted) you can retrieve the clicked option in the following manner:

```
// your_script.php
<?php
// Superglobal post which contains the right option
$selectedOption = $_POST['image'];
```

Comment: I dont want to create a captcha like the one above, but rather i want to know how to solve it
I dont know where to start with it so im just curious as to how i would approach it